# Dynamically limit choices for Foreignkey in Django models based on another foreign key in the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have these models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Dialog(models.Model):
    belong_to = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)

class Message(models.Model):
    # Dialog to which this message belongs
    part_of = models.ForeignKey(Dialog)

    # User who sends message
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='sender')
    # User who receives message 
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='receiver')
```

What I want to do is limit the choices for the sender and receiver fields so that they can only be the users to which the whole dialog belongs.
I tried this:

```
sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,
                           related_name='sender',
                           limit_choices_to={'dialog':1})
```

which limits the choices but only for members of dialog with id=1. I'm wondering if this can be done dynamically?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe there is any way to dynamically filter like you want using limit_choices_to, as you won't have access to the needed objects to form such a query there.

Instead you should probably create your own model form for message and set the queryset for those fields there. Something like below...

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.part_of and self.instance.part_of.id:
            users = self.instance.part_of.belong_to.all()
            self.fields['sender'].queryset = users
            self.fields['receiver'].queryset = users
```

Further, why `limit_choices_to` works for your example, but is not dynamically useful.

Django simply processes the `limit_choices_to` expression as an extra filter to be applied to the ModelForm fields queryset. Your expression `{dialog: 1}` is semantically no different than if you were to assign the result of `UserProfile.objects.filter(dialog=1)` to the queryset in my example.

Django does not know if a dialog with that id exists as a relation on the UserProfile, it just applies the filter. In this case a dialog with id 1 exists and so it works out. If you stick an invalid dialog id in your example instead..it would evaluate to an empty queryset and you would have get 0 choices in your form.

It cannot be dynamic because in `limit_choices_to` you can only create a filter expression for the UserProfile model. You have no access to the Message instance the field belongs to, nor the Dialog model the message belongs to...hence you cannot create a filter to dynamically limit to those.

Creating your own ModelForm and limiting the queryset for the field there, where you have the information you need, is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to do smth like this, but first: its not _forms.py_ its _models.py_ and second: its strange that I can get access with a number, so it already knows that there is such dialog object, but can't do it dynamically (

Comment: I don't know what your referring to with the models.py vs forms.py.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain more how limit_choices_to works / doesn't work the way you want...

Comment: Well, seems like have to do all manually. Anyway thanks for trying to help )

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to dynamically filter fields within a model in Django. To ensure no user inputs incorrect data, I would edit the clean method to perform an additional layer of validation. (So an admin may think they can add any senders/receivers but if they submit an instance with senders/receivers that do not belong to the User of the dialog, it will give a validation error. This will prevent users from adding incorrect data to the database outside of your website.

Adding filters to your website however, (i.e., the views themselves), can be easily done by overriding the initialise method of the related form for the view.

If Django adds dynamic filters to model fields, making websites will be far too easy.

Answer (score -1):

If instances of `Message` all belong to a `Dialog`, why not create a field `messages` on the `Dialog` model? Then, you could attach a sender and receiver to each `Dialog`. In short, something along these lines:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

class Message(models.Model):
    # Other fields
```

Sender and receiver of the Message are then always those to which the Dialog belongs.

Comment: This idea is unacceptable, because sender-receiver is different for each message. When I'm posting something - I'm sender and you're receiver and vice versa. So in same dialog sender-receiver may change