# How do I get get a model objects own ID for limit_choices_to?

Tags: python, django

How do I limit choices of a ForeignKey to Objects which have a ForeignKey to an object I also have a ForeignKey too?

```
class ExtendedProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='extended_profile')
dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="date of birth")
prefered_profile = models.ForeignKey('Trainer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, related_name='main_profiles', limit_choices_to={ 'owner' : ____ })

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ExtendedProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

ExtendedProfile is an extension Django's own User Model so has a OneToOneField type ForeignKey.

Trainer is a different model of a profile, where there may be more than one Trainer with the same ForeignKey (field name 'owner') to User.

I'm basically trying to ensure that 'prefered_profile' can only be objects owned by the same user as ExtendedProfile is... How do I get a value of self on a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by instead creating a query on the modelForm. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259487/8301983) helped me out.

I won't share my exact solution as it's not gonna be relevant to what *you* a reader, is doing.